# How can i get Key from JSON Object using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I want to get key from json object. Is there any way to get key easily by retrofit 
Here i have declare my pojo model there is different key 1) uid 2) name

```
public class Account {

        @SerializedName("uid")
        @Expose
        private String uid;
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        private String name;

        /**
         * @return The uid
         */
        public String getUid() {
            return uid;
        }

        /**
         * @param uid The uid
         */
        public void setUid(String uid) {
            this.uid = uid;
        }

        /**
         * @return The name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * @param name The name
         */
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

public interface JsonObject
extends JsonStructure, Map
So, a JSONObject is a Map whose keys are of type String, and whose values are of type JSONValue.

And the javadoc of Map.keySet() says:

Set keySet()

Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map
So, what JSONObject.keySet() returns is a Set (which is quite logical, since keys of JSON objects are strings). So you want:

Set keys = posts.keyset();